# C реализация передача данных между двумя программами

Tags: c, ввод

Как реализовать передачу данных от одной программы к второй **без чтения файлов**. К примеру: первая программа генерирует имя и записывает его в массив а вторая ждет ввода имени с **клавиатуры**, и мы должни передать содержимое этого массива вместо ввода. (my_pipe не прокатит).

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5 но если вы хотите именно имитировать нажатие клавиш - т.е. вторая программа выполняет чтение потока ввода - то тут уж без перенаправления вряд ли обойдется...

Comment: Что такое "my_pipe" и почему оно "не прокатит"?

Comment: man 3 mkfifof
mkfifo - make FIFOs (named pipes)
Create named pipes (FIFOs) with the given NAMEs.
Самый простой пример:
В командной строке выполняем команду mkfifo my_pipe
Пишем и запускаем программу потребителя, которая открывает my_pipe как обычный файл и виснет на ожидании чтения.
Пишем и запускаем программу поставщика, которая открывает my_pipe на запись и пишет данные туда.
Начинается обмен данными по каналу.
Здесь существенен порядок(!) запуска этих программ. Если первым запустить производителя, то программа свалится по попытке записи в канал, из которого никто не читает.

Comment: А можно по точнее про перенаправление.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй безымянные каналы(pipe)

пример:
cat | my_prog

тут программа cat будет получать ввод с клавиатуры и пересылать его программе my_prog.

Безымянный канал обозначается символом "|" и служит для перенаправления вывода одной программы на ввод другой программы.